# Abbreviated function template. "Constraint auto const&" type works, but "Constaint const auto&" fails

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++20

For boost container hash, I needed to provide an ADL-reachable `hash_value`. I wanted to disable implicit conversions, so I wrote it as a template that forced the parameter to be the class type.

```
inline auto hash_value(std::same_as<ClassType> const auto& key) -> std::size_t;
```

To my surprise, it failed, but worked if I swapped the order of `const` and `auto`.

In order to build up a deeper understanding: How can I conceptually interpret this situation? The parameter has a placeholder type `const auto&` and is given a specifier that denotes a constraint, I thought until now. But this rather appears to be a case where the sequence `constraint auto` is a grammar that's specially detected and the mechanism fails if I reorder the type specifiers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> mechanism fails if I reorder the type specifiers

Correct. Because the constraint is not a type specifier on its own. Grammatically, it's part of the [placeholder type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec.auto.general#nt:placeholder-type-specifier) itself

```
placeholder-type-specifier:
    type-constraintopt auto
    type-constraintopt decltype ( auto )
```

There is no room there for other specifiers. Conversely, this *does work*:

```
inline auto hash_value(const std::same_as<ClassType> auto& key) -> std::size_t;
```

If you are in the <s>wrong</s> left const camp, and not the right camp.

Comment: Thanks, I now see the light without being [self-immolated](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#8.sentence-2).

Comment: Thank you!  I did not know this, and wish I could give you _all the upvotes_.